# ¿Proceden "napia" y "tapia" del caló?

Tags: etimología, coloquialismos, españa, sufijos, caló

Ayer descubrí que la palabra catalana *ganàpia* es una construcción con sufijo caló:

> [**ganàpia**](http://www.diccionari.cat/lexicx.jsp?GECART=0068561)
>   `[1653; deriv. de gana amb el sufix caló -àpia, -ípia]`
>
> m i f Persona adolescent o adulta que fa coses pròpies d'una criatura.

Es decir: *ganàpia* deriva de "gana" con el sufijo caló -àpia, -ípia y se refiere a la persona adolescente o adulta que hace cosas propias de una criatura.

Curiosamente, es un sufijo que el diccionario de catalán solo atribuye a esta única palabra.

A partir de allí, me puse a trasladar el descubrimiento a la lengua castellana, así que en el DLE busqué por aquellas palabras terminadas por "apia" y me encontré unas cuantas:

*aeroterapia, aromaterapia, aromatoterapia, balneoterapia, bioterapia, capia, chapia, cinesiterapia, cobaltoterapia, crioterapia, electroterapia, ergoterapia, escolapio,, pia, farmacoterapia, fisioterapia, fitoterapia, fototerapia, gemoterapia, helioterapia, hidroterapia, hormonoterapia, inmunoterapia, kinesioterapia, kinesiterapia, laborterapia, magnetoterapia, masoterapia, mecanoterapia, melapia, mesoterapia, metaloterapia, musicoterapia, napia, opoterapia, prosapia, psicoterapia, quimioterapia, quinesioterapia, quinesiterapia, radioterapia, radiumterapia, reflexoterapia, sarapia, sarrapia, seroterapia, sicoterapia, sueroterapia, talasoterapia, tapia, terapia, -terapia, termoterapia, tilapia, vacunoterapia*

Mirando con detenimiento la lista, pocas usan estrictamente el sufijo *-apia* y suelen usar *-terapia* u otras, cuando usan. Hay localismos (*chapia*, de Honduras) pero encontré dos que sí me suenan del habla coloquial: *napia* y *tapia*.

> [**napia**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QEnG66t)
>   `De or. inc.`
>
> 1. f. coloq. Nariz de una persona, especialmente cuando es muy grande. U. m. en pl. con el mismo significado que en sing.
>
> [**tapia**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Z7ugCOs)
>   `De or. inc.`
>
> 1. f. Cada uno de los trozos de pared que se hacen de una sola vez con tierra amasada y apisonada en un encofrado.
> 2. f. Tierra amasada y apisonada con que se hace una tapia.
> 3. f. Pared formada de tapias.
> 4. f. Muro de cerca.
> 5. f. Constr. Medida superficial que en Madrid era de 49 o 50 pies cuadrados.
>
> *tapia real*
>
> 1. f. Constr. Pared que se forma mezclando la tierra con alguna parte de cal.
>
> *más sordo, da que una tapia*
>
> 1. loc. adj. coloq. Muy sordo.

En el caso del sufijo *-ipia* hubo menos suerte entre las que encontré:

*calcotipia, calitipia, calotipia, catatipia, celotipia, cromotipia, daguerrotipia, electrotipia, escripia, estenotipia, estereotipia, fototipia, galvanotipia, linotipia, monotipia, platinotipia, ripia, serendipia*

Casi todas ellas usan el sufijo *-tipia* que viene del griego τυπία -typía, derivado de τύπος týpos 'molde'. Y luego está [*serendipia*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Xem9fCc) que parece de la antigua denominación de Sri Lanka que se hace en el cuento *Three Princess of Serendip*.

Pero bueno, que me estoy yendo del tema. La cuestión aquí es que he encontrado dos palabras, *napia* y *tapia*, que el DLE recoge de origen incierto, pero que a la vez son coloquiales, de uso en España y que tienen un sufijo caló. ¿Hay manera de descubrir si realmente son palabras de origen caló?

Encuentro un artículo como [*Palabras como «currar», «molar», «chaval», «napia» o «camelar» proceden de la lengua romanó*](https://www.lavozdegalicia.es/noticia/lugo/2009/07/07/palabras-currar-molar-chaval-napia-camelar-proceden-lengua-romano/0003_7832004.htm), pero no da referencias.

Comment: *Napia* tiene todas las pintas, pero *tapia*, no lo creo. No es una palabra coloquial, además; se puede usar en cualquier registro.

Comment: En caló nariz es "naquí"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En primer lugar, te cito a Corominas para *tapia*:

> TAPIA. princ. S. XIII, 'trozo de pared que se hace con tierra amasada y apisonada en una horma', 'pared formada de tapias'. Vieja palabra común a las tres lenguas romances peninsulares y a la lengua de Oc, y propagada desde España al árabe y hasta el turco; en catalán se halla desde 1169 y en mozárabe desde el S. X. Hay que suponer una antigua base hispánica *TAPIA, para nombrar este objeto, que ya era típico de la Hispania romana; probte. formado con ¡TAP!, onomatopeya del apisonamiento, comp. el cat. y oc. *tap, tapàs*, 'arcilla', y *atap(e)ir* 'aplastar o apisonar con los pies', 'tupir'.

Es decir, que le da un origen onomatopéyico y muy antiguo. Esto descarta el caló como posible origen.

En cuanto a *napia*, no aparece en el Corominas, y en el DLE solo aparece registrado dese 2001 y ya por entonces su origen era incierto. Lo único que te puedo comentar es que se originó a finales del siglo XIX, a juzgar por los primeros casos entontrados en la hemeroteca:

> Si una chula del barrio se viera insultada por un *tiriyas*,
>   San Lorenzo de fijo le daba en las *napias* con las *parriyas*; [...].
>
> La Época (Madrid). 10/8/1889, n.º 13.279, página 3.

Aunque el diario sea de Madrid, el texto pertenece a una zarzuela titulada *Cádiz*, por lo que no sé si el uso de la palabra es madrileño o gaditano. Lo que sí puedo decir es que por entonces la palabra era de reciente cuño o considerada vulgar, por su uso en cursiva en el texto original.

Así que me fui a buscar el término en el Fichero General, y ahí sí se encuentran cosas interesantes. Una de las fichas dice:

> Según J. Gobello es italianismo (it. nappia [...]) recogido por el caló.

Otra ficha afirma que es "voz de germanía muy popularizada", y otra incide en que viene "del dialectal italiano". Así que sí, es probable que provenga del caló como afirmas.